# Why are the Himalayan rivers highly tortuous in the mountain reaches?

Tags: sedimentology, mountains, rivers

> "In the Himalayan reaches, the course of these rivers is highly
> tortuous, but over the Plains they display a strong meandering
> tendency and shift their courses frequently."

This is what I saw about the Himalayan rivers in my textbook. I do understand why they meander in the Plains (Northern Plains in India), but I don't get how meandering in the Plains is different from being 'tortuous' in the higher mountain reaches. What exactly is the difference between 'tortuous' and 'meandering' in this context?

Comment: do not overthink this,in the mountains a river will follow the terrain (and stay fixed in place)and on the plains the river will change where it flows as a result of the buildup of deposited material.